# Reference Error: self is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

We are facing the issue

> "Reference Error: self is not defined'

while trying to use React-data-grid. The issue is on the server side while trying to build the nodejs application using webpack. We are facing issue in the generated bundle file in the following lines

```
isOldIE = memoize(function() {          return /msie
[6-9]\b/.test(self.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());      }),
```

Could you let us know how can we fix this. It looks like the react data grid package has issues with the server side rendering.

Comment: Can you post the code showing where you defined `self` in relation to this line of code?

Comment: You haven't declared `self` within the scope of that executing code. The error message is quite clear.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/361

Comment: @redOctober13 The code expects the normal browser-defined `self` global, which is a synonym for `window` in the browser. It is absent in this server-side environment; this is basically the same as `Reference Error: window is not defined` when using `window` in Node code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`self` is likely referring to `window` which is not available on the server side...it's only available in a browser context. The `navigator` reference makes this especially apparent. This code is trying to test the user agent for Internet Explorer verison.

```
self.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()
```

As Jordan pointed out, there is an open issue [#361](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/361) regarding isomorphic rendering.

If possible, try to avoid executing that code when on the server-side. Otherwise, you'll have to wait for a patch in `react-data-grid`.

Comment: Thanks styfle. This helped in figuring out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using the following package **exenv** which restricts it check for the posted condition  only during client rendering

```
var ExecutionEnvironment = require('exenv');
if(ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM) {
  const ReactDataGrid = require('react-data-grid');
  const {Toolbar, Filters: {NumericFilter, AutoCompleteFilter, MultiSelectFilter, SingleSelectFilter}, Data: {Selectors}} = require('react-data-grid-addons');
}
```